# ¿Cómo mostrar los 30 primeros múltiplos de 3 usando un for en Java?

Tags: java, bucle-for

¿Qué es necesario poner en los signos de interrogación? Es un programa que imprime en pantalla los 30 primeros múltiplos de 3 utilizando `for` en *Java*.

```java
int numero=3;

for(numero=3; ¿? ; numero=numero+¿?){
    System.out.print(numero);
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Comment: busca como se realia un bucle for no creoque sea necesario pregutar eso, lo buscas en google

Comment: ¿Cómo le hago para hallar los multiplos?

Comment: Ya lo tienes pero que conste que por una pregunta como esta lo normal es que te la cierren porque no has intentado nada pero me has pillado animado jaj

Answer (score 2):

```
int mult = 30;

for(int i = 1; i <= mult; i++)
{             
   System.out.println(i * 3);
}
```

Se declara la **variable mult** que es la que va a indicar la cantidad de múltiplos que se quieren hallar, en este caso es **30**, pero puede ser cualquier otro, posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo for** desde **1** hasta **mult** y se va multiplicando **i * 3** y se va mostrando el resultado de esta multiplicación por consola.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso particular, en el centro del `for` puede haber dos opciones:

- Que `numero` sea menor a `(30+2)*3`, es decir `numero < (30+2)*3`
- o menor o igual a `(30+1)*3`, es decir `numero <= (30+1)*3`

Además, al final del `for`, al `numero` siempre se le sumará 3.

```java
int numero=3;
for(numero=3; numero < (30+2)*3 ; numero=numero+3){
    System.out.print(numero);
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Pero hay otra manera de hacerlo:

```java
for(int i=0; i<30 ; ++i){
    System.out.print( ((i+1)*3) + " ");
}
```

Lo que hace es mostrar `(i+1)*3`, esto 30 veces. La variable `i` es un contador empezado en `0`.

De esta manera, dependiendo del valor de `i`, mostrará diferentes resultados:

```
 0   (0+1)*3    1*3    3
 1   (1+1)*3    2*3    6
 2   (2+1)*3    3*3    9
...    ...      ...   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenemos un acumulador para comprobar el nº de multiplos que llevamos, un bucle while que se mantedra activo hasta haber alcanczado los 30 multiplos, cada vuelta aumentamos el nº en 1 y si el resto de dividir por 3 es 0 imprimimos el numero y aumentamos en uno el acumulador

```
 int acumulardor =0;
    boolean multiploAlcanzado = false;
     int i =0
    while (multiploAlcanzado == false) {         
           if(i%3==0){
            acumulador++;
            System.out.println(i);
    }
            i++
            if(acumulador ==30){
                multiploAlcanzado ==true;
     }
    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declara un contador que llegará a 30;

```
int cont = 0;
```

Y el `for` lo haces infinito hasta que `cont` sea 30:

```
for(int numero = 3; ;numero += 3){
    System.out.print(numero);
    System.out.print(" ");
    cont += 1;
    if(cont == 30) {
        break;//Sale del for
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo una buena práctica declarar `for` para luego romperlos con una condición, para ello considero más correcto utilizar un `while`, que es un `for` con condición de salida, te aconsejo que rompas la costumbre de usar un for para todo, que es Java y permite abstraerte.

Comment: @chikebox *"Te aconsejo que rompas la costumbre"* de no leer primero la pregunta y el contenido de la misma, pues las respuestas se basan en eso. Gracias por el -1 :D